# What is the time complexity of HTML DOM lookups

Tags: javascript, html, dom, big-o, time-complexity

Assuming there are no crazy optimizations (I'm looking at you Chrome).

I'm talking about raw, nasty, ain't-broke-don't-fix-it, ie v6 javascript, cost.

**The lower limit being:**

```
document.getElementById()
```

**Versus:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div') lookup.
```

Comment: If you're optimizing for IE 6, I'd urge you to reconsider the 'ain't-broke' part.

Comment: @robrich I'm not optimizing anything. Just curious. I thought the ie6 would mark the sarcasm behind 'aint-broke'. Maybe I should "air-quote" it for clarity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`getElementById` can safely assumed to be `O(1)` in a modern browser as a hashtable is the perfect data structure for the id=>element mapping.

Without any optimizations any simply query - be it a css selector, an id lookup, a class  or tag name lookup - is not worse than `O(n)` since one iteration over all elements is always enough.

However, in a good browser I'd expect it to have a tagname=>elements mapping, so `getElementsByTagName` would be `O(1)` too.

Comment: and without any optimization getElementsByTagName will have to be O(n) even in best case since the last element could be the one you're looking for

Comment: So, does that mean browsers map multiple views for each tag on write to maximize read speed? Wouldn't that be slightly more memory intensive?

Comment: The memory usage of those mappings would be irrelevant. It would be much less than e.g. a single image (such as a background image on a website) cached in memory.

Comment: It is worth noting that `getElementsByTagName` can be assumed to be O(1) because its return type, `HTMLCollection`, is live (that is, if you add a new element of the right type to the document, your `HTMLCollection` is updated behind your back), indicating that it will be pointing straight into to the browser’s internal structures. The more recently more popular `querySelectorAll`, on the other hand, returns a non-live `NodeList`, which means that it’s got to create a new array-like object each time, making it at least O(n). (Well, either that or insertion becomes utterly horrifying.)