# Random Dots Javascript / CSS starts running really slow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have a simple script that places random dots on the screen.
Using Javascriot and CSS
This works great and certain things can be controlled easily with the CSS..

The only thing is... After 30,000 dots or so... it really slows down. To a crawl.
I would like to have it go on at least into the millions of dots without bogging down.
I have a pretty powerful computer and find the results are about the same cross browser.

```
<!doctype html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ran Dots</title>

<style>
    body{
    background-color:#C82022;
    }
    .dot {
        position: absolute;
        width: 2px;
        height: 2px;
        background: black;
    }
</style>

</head><body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="textfield">num of dots</label>
  <input type="text" id="num_of_dots" value="0" />
</form>

<script>
//
function createDot(x, y){
    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.setAttribute("class", "dot");
    elem.setAttribute("style", "left:"+x+"px;top:"+y+"px;");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(elem);
    return elem;
}
//

var Count_Num_Of_Dots = 0;
//
function Add_Dot(){

        if(Count_Num_Of_Dots < 1000000){

            createDot(Math.floor(Math.random()*1900), Math.floor(Math.random()*870 + 40));
            Count_Num_Of_Dots ++;
            document.getElementById('num_of_dots').value ++;

        }else{// stop timer

            clearInterval(My_Timer_Var);

        }
}
//

// Timer
var My_Timer_Var = setInterval(function(){ Add_Dot() }, .05);
</script>

</body></html>
```

Can anyone tell me:

- what inevitably causes it to slow down?
- how can I keep these dots going efficiently and with good speed into the millions of dots?
- Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Thank you

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What inevitably causes it to slow down?

It's probably because of the time-complexity of the DOM look ups. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444074/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-html-dom-lookups).

> How can I keep these dots going efficiently and with good speed into
>   the millions of dots?

Minimize DOM lookups or get a better processor.

> Maybe there is a better way todo this?

Also, there might be better ways. You should time different techniques and measure.