# How to access the value of the input when it is deep in the component hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

lets say, I have below code in my react component three level deep  `<Foo><Bar><InputBox/><Bar></Foo>` where 'InputBox' is a presentation component

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox" ref="inputBox" name="inputBox" value={this.state.inputVal} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I would like to get the value of the input in my container component to perform the form validation. I can get the value using either vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById('inputBox').value
```

or using React ref (But the below one doesn't work when my refs are very deep)

```
this.refs.inputBox.value
```

I would like to know which approach is better in terms of performance and why? and would like to know how to access the value of the input when it is deep in the component hierarchy using React's ref approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findDOMNode vs getElementById for plain DOM elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415198/finddomnode-vs-getelementbyid-for-plain-dom-elements)

Comment: @Miah I updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

Use refs. But...

> Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy,
>   and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. Callback
>   refs are preferred.
>    - FB https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute

So instead do something like `<input ref={el => this.inputEl = el} />` and access the value as `this.inputEl.value`.

A few minor points:

- `input="text"` is not needed. That's the default
- Avoid IDs, they don't scale well (e.g. if another element elsewhere in the page is given the same ID, you have invalid HTML)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of Callback Refs, But my inputbox is created dynamically. I don't know how to create callback refs for dynamically created input field.(inputs are created inside .map loop) So I am using string refs for now as below...

`<input ref={"my-input-box-'+index} />`

Answer (score -4):

I would use innerHTML for this.

```
var input = document.GetElementByID('inputBox').innerHTML;
```

You can now use that input variable to do your validation.

Comment: Since `document.GetElementByID` doesn't exist and since the `innerHTML` property of an input element doesn't do anything … that isn't going to be remotely useful.

Comment: This is a very bad answer. Do not do this.